# How should I validate a token passed in URL in a form

Tags: angular

I'm doing a form to reset password.

So, the user receive and email, click a button that send him to a page to reset the password.

the url can be:

```
http://localhost:4200/password/reset?token=YyG30e4YyZqvbxu5Q99AhwUOAuEywD
```

or

```
http://localhost:4200/password/reset/YyG30e4YyZqvbxu5Q99AhwUOAuEywD
```

I prefer the first one, as the token is not representing any entity.

Then, when I submit the form, I do:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let token = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token');
    this.resetForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required],
      password_confirmation: ['', Validators.required],
      token: ['', Validators.required]
    }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'password_confirmation')});
    this.returnUrl = '/dashboard';
  }
```

but token is still not part of the formbuilder, so it will fail.

How should I do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of token in formbuilder to token from the queryParams.

```
ngOnInit() {
let token = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('token');
this.resetForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  password: ['', Validators.required],
  password_confirmation: ['', Validators.required],
  token: [token, Validators.required]
 }, {validator: this.matchingPasswords('password', 'password_confirmation')});
 this.returnUrl = '/dashboard';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility would be a singleton user service which holds the current user‘s token.

And to simplify the requests it might be an idea to consider appending the token to each request using an http-interceptor. Furthermore aren’t tokens used for authentification transported with the http-header ‚Authorization‘?